# Need to parse C# textbox for objectionable words

Tags: c#, xml, textbox, config

I'm part of a small "message board" type project being built in a C# Web Form.  I need to parse the user-entered text for objectionable words.  This is my first C# project and I'm not sure how to split the words in the textbox.

It's been requested that I make an XML config file to contain the words to be screened for.  Ideally, I would like to do a fark.com style replace.  I've never made an XML config file and I really just need a place to start.  All the config file information I've found has not been particularly applicable to this scenario.

Edit:

I ended up using a .txt file and splitting it on whitespace, then parsing the textbox on whitespace and comparing words.  The project leader wanted a config file, but I pitched him on the simple solution and we went for it.  Thanks for the replies.

Comment: look at the msdn documentation about string; you may use string.split() or a regex;

Comment: what is fark.com style? i know gangnam though...

Comment: Luis, by "fark.com" style, I meant the method they use for language filtering.  Certain objectionable words in comments will be replaced with innocuous words with similar sound (i.e. "f**k" becomes "fark").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making an XML config file just to filter a bunch of words probably isn't the best way to go there, considering it's most-likely just going to be a giant list of strings...

If it's not, have a look at the [XmlDocument Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the [System.Xml namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) I assume you're aware of the format for XML documents but, if not, [here is a simple example](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml). The format is pretty much open to whatever XML tags you want, but the XmlDocument class I linked you to does have some fairly annoying catches that you'll come across while implementing it.

In terms of splitting the user text, it's fairly easy to hide "bad" words in another string so I'm not sure `String.Split()` is even what you want either. You will probably want to Regex it.

With that said, I came across [this blog post](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/07/03/simple-net-profanity-filter) a while ago that offers a simple profanity filter for .NET using Regex. Perhaps it will suit your needs.

Comment: Good point on hiding bad words within others.  But if you choose to care about that, now you have to consider all the false-positives.  Complexity just shot through the roof.

Comment: Yes you're right, but with a profanity filter it always will. Someone will always try to get around it once it's figured out.

Comment: @DonBoitnott: This is a reply to your above comment on your answer. I didn't think about the false positives. That does pose another challenge that I don't really have the answer to. Perhaps a white-list as you suggested? Up goes the complexity again...

Answer (score 1):

An XML file won't scale well, especially if accessed concurrently. You'd better be using a database engine for such a task.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how large this "bad words list" will be, and whether you expect it to change.

If it's pretty static, I would load the list from your XML file into some kind of in-memory collection.  Then for each line of text you receive, parse the line into words, and then check each word for its existence in the collection.

If it's going to change frequently, and you need to pick up on those changes quickly, then you want more random access...that means a database.  Hitting an XML repeatedly would be a performance drag.

Either way, split the string and react to each hit.

The string can be split up using something like:

```
myLineOfText.Split(new String[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: If you don't want very bad performance for largish lists, that in-memory collection had better be a Dictionary of some sort...

Comment: I have to disagree with a string split. Imagine the word "otto" is a profane word: 1. "Hello" 2. "Goodbye" 3. "OTTO" 4. "HelloOtto"... In those examples, it is expected that 3. and 4. are filtered, yet only 3. is filtered when String.Split(" ").... is used.

Comment: @Brandon As I stated in my comment to your answer, how do you justify that against the false positives, such as "assassin", and "assess", and "pass", and "sass", etc...  Just filter them all and walk away?  You're not left with much, unless you also intend to positively filter all the _good words too_?

Comment: Remember that an in-memory dictionary won't allow changes made to the file be considered right away. Unless you load it from file on every request which is IMHO not a good idea.